# Junit and Mockito: How to test whether a method calls a method?

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to wrap my head around mockito and was wondering how I would test if a method calls a method!

So here is class with its method inside it:

```
public class RegisterController {

    public void regHandle(UserDataObject user1){

        ValidateRegisterInputController validate = new ValidateRegisterInputController();
        validate.validateInputHandle(user1); }
```

How would I test that regHandle(UserDataObject) calls validate.validateInputHandle(user1); ?

I'm sure this is a super simple test, but I really can't figure out how to test this.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975470/how-to-write-a-junit-testcase-for-a-void-method-that-creates-a-new-object/17975957#17975957

Comment: As is, you can't. You need to extract the `ValidateRegusterInputController` variable creation from the method and mock it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis not actually correct given PowerMock

Comment: @JohnB Can you expand on your answer in your linked answer? I don't see how you can hijack the constructor call.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis link added to answer

Comment: @JohnB Cool stuff, I'm going to look at PowerMock source to see how they do that.

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways of writing a test for a method which instantiates some other class.  I wrote about two of them in my article on the Mockito wiki, at http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation

Both the techniques that I describe involve refactoring your code to make it more testable.

Answer (score 1):

You would create a mock of ValidateRegisterInputController and then pass it on construction, then you would do:
Mockito.verify(mock).validateInputHandle(user1).

I strongly suggest you do not do this type of testing though. Instead of that, ask yourself how can you write an unit test that checks that what you wanted to validate was valid.

for example, check that after calling regHandle user1.isValid() is equals to true.

Comment: This would only work if `RegisterController` only operated on a single instance of `ValidateRegisterInputController`. The code creates a new instance each time the method is called. If the code CAN reuse the same instance this answer would be valid. I also don't know that verifing `isValid` is better than verifying a call to a mock. What if the method should be called even if it is already set? How would the call be verified. You are making a lot of assumptions in your answer regarding the code and requirements.

Comment: I am just saying that from personal experience the code reads better and tests betters if you refactor it so you are not dependant on mocks