# Junit for caching through JNDI

Tags: junit, jndi

I am using below mentioned code to get the cache but it will work at server environment need to write Junit test case for the same , could some one please help me out.

I am using EasyMock for mocking.

```
public Object get(final Object key, final String jndiName) throws CacheException{
            DistributedMap cacheMap = null;
            try {
                  final InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
                  cacheMap = (DistributedMap) ic.lookup(jndiName);
                  return cacheMap.get(key);
            } catch (final Exception ex) {
                  throw new Exception(ex)
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is answered by this question: [how-to-write-a-junit-testcase-for-a-void-method-that-creates-a-new-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975470/how-to-write-a-junit-testcase-for-a-void-method-that-creates-a-new-object/17975957#17975957)

It is challenging to use mocks in a method that creates a new instance. Use one of the proposed solutions to get around this: Powermock, Factory, Override